# How to iterate over and sort QGridLayout items

Tags: c++, loops, qt, sorting

I have a `QGridLayout` with 225 children `QTextEdit`. I need to populate a `QString board[15][15]` array with their text values based on the position of each `QTextEdit`. If I was doing this the *long* way, I would do it like this:

```
boardArray[0][0] = ui->box0x0->toPlainText();
boardArray[0][1] = ui->box0x1->toPlainText();
boardArray[0][2] = ui->box0x2->toPlainText();
...
```

That seems like a pretty bad solution. So I decided to iterate over the `QTextEdit` children of the grid so I could manipulate each one;

```
QList<QTextEdit*> textEdits = ui->gridLayout->findChildren<QTextEdit *>();
for (QTextEdit* box : textEdits) {
    // We don't know where this box is though
    board[ ??? ][ ??? ] = box->toPlainText();
}
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a `QTextEdit.row` property or anything, so I do not know the order they are in or how I could populate my `board` array without it being random.

Do y'all have any ideas about how I can organize the `QTextEdit` widgets into my `board` array? I wasn't sure how I could do this with that iteration technique.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the grid layout should work, something along the following lines (I haven't tested this):

```
for (int i{0}; i < ui->gridLayout->rowCount(); ++i)
{
  for (int j{0}; j < ui->gridLayout->columnCount(); ++j)
  {
    auto* textEdit{static_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition(i, j)->widget()};
    board[i][j] = textEdit->toPlainText();
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a segmentation fault when I run this or other variations that try and get the widget from a position... Not sure why

Comment: @GreenDev3 Depending on exactly how your `QGridLayout` is populated you may need to check that the value returned by `ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition(i, j)` is non-null.